# Functional Programming in Scala

Tags: scala

My question is about Lambda in Unit6.4

```
trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
}

type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)

val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt
```

Why `"_.nextInt"` can equal `"x => x.nextInt"`.

In Java8, `(RNGｒ) -> r.nextInt()` can be replaced like `RNG::nextInt`(a function reference).

So I want to understand what's the difference between `"_.nextInt"` and `"RNG::nextInt"`,and why `"val int: Rand[Int] = x.nextInt"`, "x" can not match RNG but `"_"` can.

[image]

Comment: A somewhat more descriptive title would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type alias

```
Rand[Int]
```

by definition stands for the type

```
RNG => (Int, RNG)
```

Since you declare the value `int` to be of type `Rand[Int]`, the compiler expects to see a function of type `RNG => (Int, RNG)` on the right hand side.

The right hand side is

```
_.nextInt
```

which is a syntactic sugar shortcut for

```
ф => ф.nextInt
```

with some synthetic variable `ф`.

Since the expected type of this function is known to be `RNG => (Int, RNG)`, the type of the argument `ф` can be assumed to be `RNG`:

```
(ф: RNG) => ф.nextInt
```

Since for an `ф: RNG` the expression `ф.nextInt` is known to have the type `(Int, RNG)`, the type of the function literal matches the expected type `RNG => (Int, RNG)`.

---

Meanwhile, the definition

```
val int: Rand[Int] = x.nextInt
```

is meaningless, because it contains an undefined symbol `x`.

---

Java 8 provides special shortcuts for lambdas that simply invoke some methods on objects. Your particular use case is covered by [Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which, given class definition

```
class Foo {
   public Bar bar() { .... }
}
```

allows you to replace the lambda

```
(Foo f) -> f.bar()
```

by just

```
Foo::bar
```